# Magento 2 StoreManagerInterface already exists in context object in compilation

Tags: magento2, error, blocks, magento-2.1, compilation

I am getting this error in my extension.

> PackageName\ModuleName\Block\Enhanced
>   Incorrect dependency in class PackageName\ModuleName\Block\Enhanced in 
>                   /var/www/html/app/code/PackageName/ModuleName/Block/Enhanced.php
>   \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface already exists in context object

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
    array $data = []

)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;      
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to inject `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in your constructor because the parent class already does that.

I assume your block extends `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` which already has the following code:

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
{
    $this->validator = $context->getValidator();
    $this->resolver = $context->getResolver();
    $this->_filesystem = $context->getFilesystem();
    $this->templateEnginePool = $context->getEnginePool();
    $this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
    $this->_appState = $context->getAppState();
    $this->templateContext = $this;
    $this->pageConfig = $context->getPageConfig();
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Thus you can replace your code with:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,   
    array $data = []

)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
}
```

Comment: Ah...13 seconds too late.

Comment: @Marius haha. I still find interesting to see how two non native english speakers explain the same thing =)

Comment: @Marius and Raphael +2. So quickly.

Answer (score 5):

you don't need to add `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager` as a dependency to your class.
You already have access to an inplementation of `StoreManagerInterface` in the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context` class.
[See this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Template/Context.php#L126).

So you can make your constructor look like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    array $data = []

)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
}
```

And you will still be able to access `storeManager` member variable like this `$this->_storeManager`.

Answer (score 5):

Following methods are available in `Context` object(`\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context`)

```
print_r(get_class_methods($context))

Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => getResolver
    [2] => getValidator
    [3] => getFilesystem
    [4] => getLogger
    [5] => getViewFileSystem
    [6] => getEnginePool
    [7] => getAppState
    [8] => getStoreManager
    [9] => getPageConfig
    [10] => getCache
    [11] => getDesignPackage
    [12] => getEventManager
    [13] => getLayout
    [14] => getRequest
    [15] => getSession
    [16] => getSidResolver
    [17] => getScopeConfig
    [18] => getInlineTranslation
    [19] => getUrlBuilder
    [20] => getAssetRepository
    [21] => getViewConfig
    [22] => getCacheState
    [23] => getEscaper
    [24] => getFilterManager
    [25] => getLocaleDate
)
```