# Magento2 can't inject dependency in Class which extends from \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I'm trying to extend a Block in Magento, the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` block and Inject a dependency on it, but I've hit a wall and just get this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Holy\Demo\Block\Product\ListProduct::__construct() must implement interface Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface, instance of Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper given, called in /var/www/html/generated/code/Holy/Demo/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /var/www/html/app/code/Holy/Demo/Block/Product/ListProduct.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/generated/code/Holy/Demo/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php(14): Holy\Demo\Block\Product\ListProduct->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data), Array) #1 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Holy\Demo\Block\Product\ListProduct\Inte in /var/www/html/app/code/Holy/Demo/Block/Product/ListProduct.php on line 14
```

This is the **di.xml** of my module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Holy\Demo\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

And this is my Block class:

```
<?php

namespace Holy\Demo\Block\Product;

/**
 * Product list
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState
     */
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
//        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState,
       array $data = []
   )
   {
       $this->stockState = $stockState;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

    public function getStockQty($product) {
      // TODO: Don't use objectManager, Inject the \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface on the constructor of the block
      // $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      // $_stockState = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
      // return $_stockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

       return $this->stockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to get it working by adding all of the parent class arguments from it's constructor to my constructor, but this does not seem like a good approach to me as  if in a Magento update a new dependency is added to the parent class, won't that break my module?

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->stockState = $stockState;
    parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper , $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
}
```

Comment: Try to clear your cache and remove var/generation.

Comment: thanks but i tried that already

Comment: In your updated info, it's ok! Magento used this approach.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh yes you are correct

Comment: if in a Magento update a new dependency is added to the parent class, could that break my module?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, I think Magento will have a release note and a guide for migration module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child arguments constructor should inherit from parent class:

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository, 
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper, 
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }
```

Remember to remove `var/generation` and clear cache also.

**[EDIT]**

For this answer: [Magento 2 StoreManagerInterface already exists in context object in compilation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136209/magento-2-storemanagerinterface-already-exists-in-context-object-in-compilation/136211#136211). We don't need to inject `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in our child class, but we inject `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context` in the construct. This class has `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in its constructor already.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Why do I need to pass in all the arguments from the parent? I've read in [other answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136211/6549) that you don't need to inject dependencies in your constructor if the parent class already has them.  What if in a Magento update a new dependency is added to the parent class, won't that break my module?

Comment: Also, I don't have a `var/generation` directory, I think becuase I'm working in developer mode, but I cleared the cache and ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade; php bin/magento setup:di:compile;` which from the [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html) I believe should take care of any cache issues

Comment: @Holy https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136211/6549 . We don't need to inject `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in our child, but we inject `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context` in the construct. This class has `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in its constructor already.

Comment: yes, that's why I'm wondering why I need to add them if it's in the parent constructor already, see my updated Question.

Comment: can you update your answer to include the `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState` dependency from my question?  Just to make it clearer to others who may view this later. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, @Holy I updated.